# Get messages about the status of a WebSocket in Elm

Tags: websocket, elm

I'm looking at Elm and in particular the WebSocket library.  With the high level functions, "[T]he effect manager tries to reconnect with an exponential backoff strategy."  That is all well and good, but if there is something truly wrong with the client or the server (say the server is down, or is trying to tell the client to login before opening the websocket).  Simply trying again more and more slowly will never fix the problem.

Is there some way to get messages about the status of the websocket's connection so that I can show the user a helpful message like "The server is down." or "Authentication is required for this feature." and the like?

I imagine it working something like:

```
subscriptions model =
  listen "ws://echo.websocket.org" WSMessage
  status "ws://echo.websocket.org" WSStatus
```

Comment: The [`WebSocket.LowLevel`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/websocket/1.0.2/WebSocket-LowLevel) package looks like it might have the greater flexibility you're looking for, at the price of more complexity.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/elm-lang/websocket/issues/14) and [proposed patch](https://github.com/elm-lang/websocket/pull/19) that covers this case, but at the moment there is not a solution that works in the [approved WebSocket library](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/websocket/latest).

(This answer current as of September 28, 2017)